# rndnumber is not working in way I want

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

HI I'm new to VB and I want to make a program that will randomize number betwen minimum number and maximum number.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rnumber As Integer

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rndnumber As Random
        Dim number As Integer
        rndnumber = New Random
        number = rndnumber.Next(1, 10001)
        rnumber = number

        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If rnumber < TextBox1.Text Or rnumber > TextBox2.Text Then
            Dim rndnumber As Random
            Dim number As Integer
            rndnumber = New Random
            number = rndnumber.Next(1, 10001)
        Else
            Timer1.Stop()
            Label4.Text = rnumber.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

When I click the button nothing happends, the program does not even freeze!

Please help, TNX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance of Random class in every tick, instead do it in Form_Load:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim rnumber As Integer
  Dim rndnumber As Random

  Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rndnumber = New Random
  End Sub

  '...

  Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If rnumber < TextBox1.Text Or rnumber > TextBox2.Text Then
        rnumber = rndnumber.Next(1, 10001) 'changed from "number"
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
        Label4.Text = rnumber.ToString
    End If
  End Sub
```

Notice that you never assigned the generated value to `rnumber`, so your code will not work as you expect, so I changed `number =` to `rnumber =` up there.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to set:

```
Timer1.Enabled = True
```

Either in code, or in the properties windows of the Timer object on the form.